# Call a function in a script

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I am writing a script starting with these

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(....)
```

Then I want to define a function inside or outside this file which uses the value of driver... but whatever I do, I will not keep the value of driver, even if I copy and paste these lines into the function... My functions input variable does not include driver... but inside it, it will need driver... It would be like:

```
def test(i,j)
```

I am new to Python. I know in some languages, you can call driver a global variable and then its value will be carried on into the function... but how shall I do it in Python

Comment: Format all code by highlighting it and pressing ctrl+k.

Comment: Please show us the complete code of the file that you're copy-pasting these lines into.